# probability that of three people, two fall into one specific category and one into another

Tags: probability

Given the data in the table for a sample of 750 people,
three people were selected at random from this sample
What's the probability that two of them have dark hair and brown eyes and the other has medium hair and green eyes?

[image: Data table]

The solution is 
$[(92/750)\times (91/749)\times (55/748)]\times 3 = 0.00329$.

On my first attempt, I got exactly what the solution provided, only missing the "*3" part, which I do not understand why it's there. Please provide an explanation?
I'm a beginner on my journey of stats, so there will be quite a bit of knowledge which I won't be familiar with.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the three people are Amy, Ben and Cal.

There are three possible choices for which one of the three of them is the one with medium* hair and green eyes. That is, you need to add the probabilities that:

- Amy and Ben have dark hair and brown eyes while Cal has medium hair and green eyes
- Amy and Cal have dark hair and brown eyes while Ben has medium hair and green eyes
- Cal and Ben have dark hair and brown eyes while Amy has medium hair and green eyes

* I've never heard hair color described as "medium" before.

Comment: Right, so (92/750)*(91/749)*(55/748) is only for 1 scenario, and since there are 3 scenarios, I need to x 3. Got it.